# clustering coefficient and average distance in Watt-Strogatz networks

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, computational-mathematics

we want to prove that clustering coefficient in Watts–Strogatz Graphs when p=0 (probability of having random edges) can be obtained using the following formula:
C(0) = 3(c-1)/2(2c-1)
where 2c= mean k(average degree of the nodes)
and we also want to prove that the average distance between the nodes in such conditions can be obtained using the following formula:
N/4c
where N is the total number of nodes in the graph
we want to prove these formulas in such conditions using induction, testing different graphs with such properties, using definitions of these properties or any other method
Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).